# Angular: Check response type from Observable

Tags: angular

I got a very basic api call that i am making. This function calls API server delete, which randomly either responds with NoContent (204) or Ok (200).

I am trying to figure out whether observable returned a 204 or 200 response, and don't know how to do this properly.

Advice is appreciated. Sample code below:

```
checkNoContent(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.delete<any>('localhost:5001/api/test');
}

testingFunction() {
   this.checkNoContent().subscribe(
        (res) =>   { //check if NoContent }, 
        (error) => { console.info(error); });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use '.pipe' method in your http call and then use rxjs 'catchError', triggering an error handler in the callback:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'

checkNoContent(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.delete<any>('localhost:5001/api/test')
   .pipe(catchError((error: any) => this.errorHandler(error)))
}

errorHandler (error) {
   // do whatever you want with your error and throw it to your susbscription error
   let errorCode = error.code 
   return Observable.throw(errorCode)
}

testingFunction() {
   this.checkNoContent().subscribe(
        (res) =>   { //check if NoContent }, 
        (error) => { console.info(error); // here is where your error result will appear });
    }
```

**Update:**

Using pipe with map:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

checkNoContent(): Observable<any> {
       return this.http.delete<any>('localhost:5001/api/test')
       .pipe(map(
           res => this.verifyResponseType(res),
           err => // call your error handler
       ))
    }

verifyResponseType (res) {
       return Observable.throw(res.status)
    }
```

Comment: How does this determine if response is 200 or 204?

Comment: Your server will respond with an error code, if you programmed it properly. Determining the error code is a server-side responsibility. You could use a 'switch' statement based on the error response code to trigger the proper action.

Comment: 204 is not error code it is no content success response

Comment: Oh, I see, you are right, those are response status codes. In this case I think you could use 'rxjs' map operator and trigger a function that will determine the type of your response. Check my update.

Answer (score 0):

`if (res) {}`

204 will not send a body, so res will be undefined. 200 probably sends some sort of success message. If not, then console.log res a few times and see what you’re getting. If both responses are empty, use your network tab in Chrome to see what the response actually is.

You might try searching through the Angular docs to see if the status code can be revealed.

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#methods

It looks like by manually creating the Request object, the raw http response will be returned, instead of just the body.